# Simultaneously smooth

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I came across a problem recently which can be reduced to finding numbers $m$ such that $m$ and either $5m+1$ or $5m-1$ are $\{2,3,5\}$-smooth, i.e., of the form $2^a3^b5^c$ for nonnegative integers $a,b,c.$ (Of course this is the same as checking if $m(5m\pm1)$ is $\{2,3,5\}$-smooth.)

I checked up to $10^{100}$ and found only small cases:
$$
m\in\{1, 2, 3, 5, 16\}
$$

How can I prove that this list is complete? If I was looking at $m\pm1$ I could use Størmer's theorem but that's not available here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m$ is $\{2,3,5\}$-smooth iff $5m$ is, hence $5m$ and $5m\pm1$ are consecutive $\{2,3,5\}$-smooth numbers - exactly what Størmer's theorem is about.

The case of consecutive $\{2,3,5\}$-smooth number happens to be treated as an example for Lehmer's method in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormer%27s_theorem)

Comment: (embarrassment...)